# Clustering dots in a scatterplot

Tags: r, scatter-plot

Let's say I have this `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1, 20), y = runif(20, 10, 20))
```

and I want to plot `df$y` vs. `df$x`.

Since the x values are constant, points that have identical or close y values will be plotted on top of each other in a simple scatterplot, which kind of hides the density of points at such y-values. One solution for that situation is of course to use a violin plot.

I'm looking for another solution - plotting clusters of points instead of the individual points, which will therefore look similar to a bubble plot. In a bubble plot however, a third dimension is required in order to make the bubbles meaningful, which I don't have in my data. Does anyone know of an R function/package that take as input points (and probably a defined radius) and will cluster them and plot them?

Comment: The standard "simple" solution to the problem is to use "jitter" - add small random values to your datapoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at the `sunflowerplot` function (and the `xyTable` function that it uses to count overlapping points).

You could also use the `my.symbols` function from the TeachingDemos package with the results of `xyTable` to use other shapes (polygrams or example).

Answer (score 4):

You can `jitter` the x values:

```
plot(jitter(df$x),df$y)
```

Comment: Thanks. jitter is definitely another option, but I'm still interested in clusters if that's possible. I think that clusters will have the added value of making the plot less busy.

Answer (score 3):

You could try a hexplot, using either the `hexplot` library or `stat_binhex` in ggplot2.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hexbin/

http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/stat_binhex.html

Answer (score 3):

The other standard approach (vs. jitter) is to use a partially transparent color, so that overlapping points will appear darker than "lone" points.

De gustibus, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Using transparency is another solution. E.g.:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.2, size=3)
```

When there is only one `x` value, a density plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=y)) +
  stat_density(geom="line")
```

or a violin plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_violin()
```

might also be options for displaying your data.